# How to refresh a webgrid with data instead of view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add a checkbox to a page and that page having the web grid. so if i check the checkbox it has to fire the action and return the view with some more records to the list.
But the webgrid is not refreshing and not showing the recent records. How can i solve my issue.Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

IE use client Cache.. So make sure that caching is disabled for Code. Like below..

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]        
public ActionResult GetArea(int locationId)
```